# Boundary conditions for vector wave equations

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

Assume the time-harmonic case of Maxwell's equations, one can obtain the following vector wave equations:
$$
\nabla\times(\frac{1}{\epsilon_r}\nabla\times\mathrm{H})-k_0^2\mu_r\mathrm{H}=\nabla\times(\frac{1}{\epsilon_r}\mathrm{J})
$$

What will be the expression of homogeneous boundary conditions for it? In the book "Finite Element Method in Electromagnetics" by Jianming Jin, page 183, he imposed homogeneous Dirichlet and Robin conditions such that
$$
\hat{n}\times\mathrm{H}=0
$$
on $S_1$ with
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon_r}\hat{n}\times(\nabla\times\mathrm{H})+\gamma_h\hat{n}\times(\hat{n}\times\mathrm{H})=0
$$
on $S_2$, where $\hat{n}$ is the surface unit normal. I thought of $\hat{n}\times\mathrm{H}$ as expressing the continuity condition, but what about the second boundary condition? Can someone explain to me the physical meaning of it? I just cannot see how it makes sense. Thank you!